# Is it possible to load different versions of the same assembly using MEF?

Tags: silverlight, mef, composition

I have a situation where the same assembly (say Common.dll) is included in 2 different modules (Xaps). By same assembly i mean an assembly having the same namespaces and classes but different implementations of the classes / operations.

Now both these modules will get placed in a single shell application and their respective xaps downloaded via the downloadcatalog. Both the xaps will contain within them a Common.dll, however with different implementations.

I tried using different CompositionContainers, one each for the modules hoping that the seperate containers would isolate the modules and their dependencies. Didn't work . **Surpisingly though**, what it did was use the **first** downloaded instance of Common.dll. This is different from typically same assembly overwriting the first one and using the latest loaded assembly, which give me a glimmer of hope.

The compositioncontainer has the ability to ReleaseExports. Would this help me ?

Coneceptually, I'm thinking that if we sequentially satisfy the imports and then release, each module should get an instance of the correct Common.dll operations.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried giving your assemblies a [strong name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wd40t7ad.aspx)? This should ensure that dependencies are resolved to the exact same assemblies as the ones you compiled against.